# Form Parameters not present with link_to :remote => true and CapyBara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have a remote link_to defined as such

```
link_to "Publish", resource_path, data: { method: :patch, remote: true, params: { resource:{ published: true } }.to_param }
```

When clicking this link manually within a browser everything is working as expected and the correct parameters are being sent to the update action and all is good.

When running a test to replicate this using Turnip, RSpec, Capybara and Poltergeist I'm having no such luck and this is down to the form parameters not being present ie: "param is missing or the value is empty:"

Is this a limitation of Poltergiest? or a configuration issue?

The test is successfully clicking this link, and the correct action is being called with a HttpMethod of PATCH as expected - just no parameters are present for the Form.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/532
...and https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11384

It seems to be a Poltergeist issue. To make it work:

- Only use GET or POST in data-method
- Set original http method in data-params as _method attribute

For your link:

```
link_to "Publish", resource_path, data: { method: :post, remote: true, params: { _method: :patch, resource:{ published: true } }.to_param }
```

... or something like that.